# jQuery fadeOut doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fadeto

```
$(div1.children().get(0)).fadeTo(0, 0.1);
```

Doesn't work :( But if I specify fateOut instead of fadeTo, then it works! So how do I make it work? The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="div1">
<a><img/></a>
<a><img/></a>
<a><img/></a>
</div>
```

I've tested in IE9 and in Chrome.

Comment: @David: He's not, he's just doing it in a really weird way.

Comment: How would you do it the right way?

Comment: @Matt, ah! You're absolutely right; I didn't see the extra parenthesis following the `get()`...my bad. :/

Comment: There is no "right" way. This way is more efficient `$(div1.children()[0]).fadeTo(0, 0.1)` and this way is more readable `div1.children().first().fadeTo(0, 0.1)`. As an alternative you could use `div1.children(':first').fadeTo(0, 0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

fadeTo(100, 0) will work better =D

the syntax is:

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity, [ callback ] )
```

Andy

Answer (score 0):

A duration of 0 disables the effect. Try a duration of 'fast' or 100 (fast is 200ms, slow is 600 ms).

Comment: Can you give a url to a test so we can work on exactly the same code?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working for me :-) check it out http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/SnzJM/

Answer (score 0):

This one works:
$($(div1.children().get(CurrentPosition)).children().get(0)).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
I think the reason is that fading must apply to the image, not to it's container. Although it does seem strange to me.